# Missing required properties: notificationCustomizationOptions error when using MC-Cordova-Plugin on Android

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, cordova

I am implementing the [MC-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin) into an app. I am able to create an android build but when running it on a device, I receive this error.

[image: notificationCustimaztionOptions error]

I have set this preference inside the android platform in the config.xml, like the documentation says. I believe it should help set the property that the error is complaining is missing.

```
<preference name="com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notification_small_icon" value="ic_notification" />
```

I am running:
Cordova 7.1.0, Cordova-Android 7.1.1

Any ideas why this error is occurring? And how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin is unable to find `ic_notification` in your Android application's resources then it will not set the NotificationCustomizationOptions in the MarketingCloudConfig.

If you haven't done so, you will need to package a set of icons in your project that will be added to the Android /res/drawable folders.  The name of the icon doesn't have to be `is_notification` but you need to make sure your config.xml uses the correct name.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file